# Table is there, but all the attributes are missing

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I have written several files containing PHP codes which goes like this: a log in page is created and you enter your username, password and name, and your cookie salted and hashed so no one can edit your cookie. Upon entering your details, you SHOULD be able to see your data appear in the "user" table. However, what I am getting in MySQL is  "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0000 seconds.)"

I have named the file below "connect2000.php":

```
<?php

$dbserver = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "tutorial";

$dbcon = mysqli_connect($dbserver, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if(!$dbcon) {
   die("Error connecting to database: " . mysqli_error());
  }
  echo "You have connected successfully";

mysqli_select_db($dbcon, $dbname) or die("Unable to select database: " .    
mysqli_error());

$query = "CREATE TABLE users (
Username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
ID INT NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
Salt VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID))";

$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query);

if(!result) die("Database access failed: " . mysqli_error());
?>
```

And I have named the file below "register2000.php":

```
<?php
require_once 'connect2000.php';
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tutorial") or 
die("Couldn't connect
to the server!");

//error reporting(0);

if(isset($_POST['register'])){
   if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
     $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
     $password = mysqli_real_escape_string(hash("sha512", 
     $_POST['password']));
     $name = "";
     if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
       $name = mysqli_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
     }
       $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE
       `username` = '$username'"));
       if($check != '0') {
          die("That username already exists! Try <i>$username" .rand(1, 50). 
       "</i> instead
          <a href = 'register2000.php'>&larr; Back</a>");
     }
     if(!ctype_alnum($username)) {
        die("Username contains special characters! Only numbers and letters 
     are permitted!
        <a href = 'register.php'>&larr; Back</a>");
     }
     if(strlen($username)>20) {
        die("Username must not contain more than 20 characters! <a href = 
   'register2000.php'>&larr; Back</a>");
     }
     $salt = hash("sha512", rand().rand().rand());
     mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `users`  (`username`, `password`, `name`, 
    `salt`) VALUES ('$username',
     '$password', '$name', '$salt')");
     setcookie("c_user", hash("sha512", $username), time() + 24 * 60 * 60, 
     "/");
     setcookie("c_salt", $salt, time() + 24 * 60 * 60, "/");
     die("Your account has been created and you are now logged in.");
   }
 }

echo "
     <body style = 'font-family : verdana, sans-serif'>
     <div style = 'width: 80%; padding: 5px 15px 5px; border: 1px solid 
    #e3e3e3;
     background-color: #fff; color: #000; margin-left: auto;>
     <h1>Register<h1>
     <br />
     <form action = '' method = 'post'>
       <table>
         <tr>
           <td>
             <b>Username:</b>
           </td>
           <td>
             <input type = 'text' name = 'username' style = 'padding: 4px;' 
       />
           </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>
             <b>Password:</b>
           </td>
           <td>
             <input type = 'password' name = 'password' style = 'padding: 
        4px;' />
           </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>
             <b>Name:</b>
           </td>
           <td>
             <input type = 'text' name = 'name' style = 'padding: 4px;' />
           </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>
             <input type = 'submit' name = 'register' value = 'Register' />
           </td>
         </tr>
       </table>
     </form>
       <br />
       <h6>
       No account? <a href='register2000.php'>Register!</a>
       </h6>
     </div>
   </body>
 ";
```

There are two other files, "index2000.php" and another file which escapes salted cookies. These two files are irrelevant to this discussion, methinks. My question is, could one of you please tell me why I am not seeing any of my data appear in my database? The table "users" HAS been created, but none of the attributes are there.

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string()` requires DB parameter be passed. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php - so does `mysqli_query()` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php - Had you been checking for errors http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php, would have avoided this question entirely.

Comment: ^^^ that's your answer ^^^

Comment: Oh dear, you're absolutely right, Fred. I had failed to insert the appropriate parameters. Thanks so much for pointing it out to me -- it may have been an obvious oversight, but I just didn't see it.

Comment: You're welcome Arnold. I take it problem solved?

Comment: You're welcome Arnold. I decided to post an answer for you below. *Cheers*

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @ArnoldPine I Google'd for another question that resembled something like this and fell upon your question. Where I noticed that I did post an answer below and the question is still considered as open. I believe the question was solved by what I posted below and should be marked as such.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `mysqli_real_escape_string()` requires DB connection parameter be passed in that function.

Consult the manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

So does the `mysqli_query()` function.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Checking for errors would have signaled those:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

---

Footnotes:

- Consider looking into using [**`mysqli` witht prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.